# Android: Communicating with common functions regardless of Class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments

I have a game with different levels, with lots of shared code between the levels. So I have MainActivity that contains all the shared code, and this loads a fragment LevelOne for each level with the level specific code in it. I need to use fragments as I also load other fragments with other UI components in them.

The level fragments all contain functions of the same name with code unique to each level, e.g. StartGame() and PauseGame(), which MainActivity calls when necessary. How do I load a single object that allows me to access these functions, regardless of what fragment it is?

E.g. in python I would do:

```
// Instantiation
int level_number = 1;  
levels = [levelOne, levelTwo]
level = levels[level_number]

// Something happens and I want to start the currently selected level somewhere in MainActivity
level.StartGame()
```

but in Java I cannot do this as I have to specify the object's class beforehand, which I do not know and instead I have to have these if conditions everywhere I refer to the level:

```
// Instantiation
LevelOne levelOne = new LevelOne();  
LevelTwo levelTwo = new LevelTwo();

// Something happens and I want to start the currently selected level somewhere in MainActivity    
if (level_number == 1) {
   levelOne.StartGame();
} elif (level_number == 2) {
   levelTwo .StartGame();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need another class for each level?

```
Level levelOne = new Level(1);  
Level levelTwo = new Level(2);
```

Comment: Because each class has markedly different code in it (each level is essentially a different game)

Comment: @James you still could have an abstract class `BaseLevelFragment` and then `LevelOne extends BaseLevelFragment`... this should drastically reduce code redundancy, while permitting custom method implementations per level. one just needs to tell apart, what they have in common and what differs.

Comment: Right so you mean instead of MainActivity have BaseLevelFragment, which will contain all common code?

Comment: @James define `public abstract class BaseLevelFragment` and move the code common to these fragments into it. keyword `abstract` prevents it's direct instantiation, since only the specific implementations matter... and one can use the common methods there, just as if they were in the same class; at least while the scope is `protected`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, this doesn't solve the original problem as I will then need to define LevelOne levelOne when referencing it from the common code in MainActivity?

Comment: @James you don't have to define all at once, that's useless. just add a `private BaseLevelFragment currentLevel`, which can hold a reference to the current instance, no matter if it's class `LevelOne` or `LevelTwo`. much code in `MainActivity` is bad design, when using `Fragment`, which is meant to be self-contained.

Comment: @NormR as far as I know you cannot use map (or lists) for different classes, only within a class